# Finding even or odd ID values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was working on a query today which required me to use the following to find all odd number ID values

```
(ID % 2) <> 0
```

Can anyone tell me what this is doing? It worked, which is great, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: (ID % 2) = 0 for selecting even numbers

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`ID % 2` is checking what the remainder is if you divide ID by 2. If you divide an even number by 2 it will always have a remainder of 0. Any other number (odd) will result in a non-zero value. Which is what is checking for.

Comment: % is the [modulus or modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), which returns the remainder of a division. For any integer, when the remainder from division by two is zero, the number is even, else it's odd. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql) is the T-SQL docs, but that applies anywhere, not just to T-SQL or computers.

Comment: (not to be confused with the modulus function which is something else)

Answer (score 39):

For finding the even number we should use

```
select num from table where ( num % 2 ) = 0
```

Answer (score 13):

As Below Doc specify

> dividend % divisor
>
> Returns the remainder of one number divided by another.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql#syntax

For Example

> 13 % 2 return 1

Next part is `<>` which denotes Not equals.

Therefor what your statement mean is
Remainder of ID when it divided by 2 not equals to 0

Be careful because this is not going to work in Oracle database. Same Expression will be like below.

```
MOD(ID, 2) <> 0
```

Answer (score 9):

`ID % 2` reduces all integer (monetary and numeric are allowed, too) numbers to 0 and 1 effectively.
Read [about the **modulo operator** in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

In oracle,

```
select num from table where MOD (num, 2) = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

dividend % divisor

Dividend is the numeric expression to divide. Dividend must be any expression of integer data type in sql server.

Divisor is the numeric expression to divide the dividend. Divisor must be expression of integer data type except in sql server.

```
SELECT 15 % 2

Output
1
```

Dividend = 15

Divisor = 2

Let's say you wanted to query

Query a list of CITY names from STATION with even ID numbers only.

Schema structure for STATION:

```
ID Number

CITY varchar

STATE varchar


select CITY from STATION as st where st.id % 2 = 0

Will fetch the even set of records 


In order to fetch the odd records with Id as odd number.

select CITY from STATION as st where st.id % 2 <> 0
```

% function reduces the value to either 0 or 1

Comment: This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for additional code examples.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to *explain* how the comparison selects odd numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It's taking the ID , dividing it by 2 and checking if the remainder is not zero; meaning, it's an odd ID.

Answer (score 1):

<> means not equal. however, in some versions of SQL, you can write !=